# A uniform magnetic field between two electromagnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is it possible? And will the nature of source circumstantially affect the charged particles in that field?

Comment: [Approximation using multiple coils](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/400/5/052038/pdf;jsessionid=C9E9CF10DCA9ACB7F7CAA0683B91FF64.c1).

Comment: Try googling Helmholtz Coil.